# React Component onClick method not evaluating bracket property accessor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a legacy React project (recently upgraded to v16) with a BUTTLOAD of babel packages, any one of which is likely responsible for this issue.

Basically, I am trying to dynamically assign an `onClick` function to a button. But the object property accessor is not being evaluated. Instead, I just get an error, which you can see below.

This is the minimum code necessary to understand the issue.

```
const myVariable = 'someFunction';

const MyComponent = props =>
  <button
    onClick={props[myVariable]('some value')}
  />

<MyComponent
  someFunction={value => () => console.log(value)}
/>
```

`TypeError: props[myVariable] is not a function`

Like, why is the expression not even evaluated in the error??

Comment: Since there are so many Babel projects that you say could be culpabable, and nothing appears immediately wrong with the code you provided, maybe you could provide what the selected code snipped look like when transpiled.

Answer (score 0):

This error `TypeError: props[myVariable] is not a function` can happen because the passed prop is not a function (obviously).

You need to give a real example, or all your babel configs, because this way, we can know if it's a problem with babel or you are passing the wrong props.

Also, if you passe it like `onClick={props[myVariable]('some value')}`, on interpreting time, it will execute the function instantly. At that time `props[myVariable]` can be other thing or is undefined and that is way you are getting the error.

The right way to do that is pass it like `onClick={() => props[myVariable]('some value')}`